# What is the difference between "select * bulk collect into... " and "fetch cursor bulk collect into"?

Tags: sql, oracle, bulk, database-cursor

In Oracle.
What is the difference between?

```
select * bulk collect into value from table
```

and

```
 fetch cursor bulk collect into value
```

I understand that when looping through a cursor and doing bulk fetching, you can limit bulk padding with the "limit" property. In that case, wouldn't it be better then to just use the "select" since it inserts the entire table at once?

In which cases to use each one?

Thank you.

Comment: `select ... bulk collect` opens, fetches and closes cursor automatically, while `fetch` is valid for explicit cursor variables only

Comment: @astentx Hi, friend. Does that mean that "select ... bulk collect" works like a cursor that automatically opens, retrieves (all data) and closes, whereas with fetch we would have to write open, loop, fetch code?

Comment: Yes. You don't need a loop though, as long as your cursor fetch doesn't have a limit clause, as it would fetch all rows at once.

Comment: don't forget bulk collect put pressure on the PGA, that's why LIMIT may be useful or even changing to PIPELINED function, Steven Feuerstein's blog has examples related to the impact on both performance and PGA costs.

Comment: It’s the same as the difference between `select into` and `fetch into`.